# 2D binary list python

Tags: python, bin

I'm having trouble making a function that places a number inside a binary grid. For instance,
if i'm given 4 3 2 1, and I have a grid that is 5x5, it would look like the following...

```
4 4 4 4 1
4 4 4 4 0
4 4 4 4 0 
4 4 4 4 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

My current code reads a text file and creates a list that is arranged in descending order. For instance if the text file contained 1 2 3, it would create a list of integers 3 2 1. Also my code prompts for a bin # which creates a binxbin square. I don't know how to actually place in a number 4 for the bin. This is the function that should place in the values which i'm stuck with.

```
def isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
    if row + block > len(bin):
        return False
    if column + block > len(bin):
        return False
    if bin[row][column] == 0 :
        return True
    else:
        return False
    for r in range(row, row+block):
        if bin[row][column] != 0:
```

Comment: In what sense is this a binary list?  I'm confused - what do you want to put in your square?  The number `4`?

Comment: So if the number 4 is the first number in the list, it will create a 4x4 block. The original list just contains 0s in the 5x5 bin. The 4 will replace the 0's. And it will start again from the top to check the 3 and 2 and 1.

Comment: I'm very confused. In what sense does the sequence `4 3 2 1`, `1 2 3` or `3 2 1` have anything to do with how you fill the 5x5 grid? Is it always a 5x5 grid?

Comment: The 5x5 grid is created with a bin value. I didn't include it but the main function prompts for a bin value and uses list comprehension to create a 5x5 grid if I put in 5 for the bin. The 4 3 2 1 is used in the example. But What I meant by the 123 and 321 is that my main function also opens a word file and sorts the list in descending order so that the biggest number comes first and then it moves down the list.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to do bin packing? As in, user input "4 3 2 1" means, "try to fit this 4x4 block in the bin given, followed by a 3x3 block, then a 2x2 block, then a 1x1 block". Is that right? And in your example, you can only fit a 4x4 and 1x1 block in the bin, so the other two are left out?

Comment: yes @Kevin that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `isSpaceFree` should return `True` if you can create a square with origin  origin `(row, column)` and size `block`, without going out of bounds or overlapping any non-zero elements. In which case, you're 75% of the way there. You have the bounds checking ready, and half of the overlap check loop.

```
def isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
    #return False if the block would go out of bounds
    if row + block > len(bin):
        return False
    if column + block > len(bin):
        return False

    #possible todo:
    #return False if row or column is negative

    #return False if the square would overlap an existing element
    for r in range(row, row+block):
        for c in range(column, column+block):
            if bin[r][c] != 0: #oops, overlap will occur
                return False

    #square is in bounds, and doesn't overlap anything. Good to go!
    return True
```

Then, actually placing the block is the same double-nested loop, but instead performing an assignment.

```
def place(bin, row, column, block):
    if isSpaceFree(bin, row, column, block):
        for r in range(row, row+block):
            for c in range(column, column+block):
                bin[r][c] = block

x = [
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
]

place(x, 0, 0, 4)

print "\n".join(str(row) for row in x)
```

Result:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hey @kevin, thanks for the help. I'm having trouble with 2 things. The first is that I have a list block[] which contains 4 3 2 1 and I want it to automatically do 4 first and see if it fits, if it does then move onto 3 and stop when it can't fit anymore blocks. The second is how would I define column and rows in my main function?

Comment: Sorry, I only know enough about the bin packing problem to provide the functions I've given. Actually solving the problem is somewhat beyond my expertise :-)